# Unable to extract folders from zip file using ZipEntry in windows

Tags: java, zip, extract

```
java.util.zip.ZipInputStream zis = new java.util.zip.ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));

    java.util.zip.ZipEntry entry;
    new File(outdir+ File.separator+"changelog").delete();
    new File(outdir+ File.separator+"media").delete();
    try {
        while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {

            File of = new File(outdir + File.separator + entry.getName());

            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                of.mkdirs();
                continue;
            } else {
                File xx = new File(of.getParent());
                if (!xx.exists()) {
                    Stack<String> todo = new Stack<String>();
                    do {
                        todo.push(xx.getAbsolutePath());
                        xx = new File(xx.getParent());
                    } while (!xx.exists());
                    while (todo.size() > 0) {
                        xx = new File(todo.pop());
                        if (!xx.exists()) {
                            xx.mkdirs();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(of), buffer.length);

            cpio(new BufferedInputStream(zis), bos, "unzip:" + entry.getName());

            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // problem with chars in entry name likely
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e+"Srikanth");
    }
    zis.close();

}
```

**entry.isDirectory()** always returing false so it is creating files instead of directories. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**ZipEntry** from **ZipInputStream** representing empty directory at end of file with \ , directory with elements with /

So that **entry.isDirectory()** not working with empty directory.

Where as **ZipEntry** from **ZipFile** working fine. I think there is difference between **ZipInputStream** and **ZipEntry** behavior.

Comment: I'm not sure about the difference between ZipInputStream and ZipEntry, but I think you're onto something regarding how the path is represented.  See this bug report:(http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6233323).

Answer (score 0):

isDirectory is not working at all with files zipped with Windows standard option "sent to/ zip files"

The format of the zip is different than format generated with tools like 7zip or Winzip. (Nice to have a standard archive compression :D)